# .NET Entity framework LINQ : The expression 't.Customer' is invalid inside an 'Include' operation

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core

#### error

> `System.InvalidOperationException`: The expression '`t.Customer`' is invalid inside an '`Include`' operation, since it does not represent a property access: '`t => t.MyProperty`'.
>
> To target navigations declared on derived types, use casting ('`t => ((Derived)t).MyProperty`') or the '`as`' operator ('`t => (t as Derived).MyProperty`'). Collection navigation access can be filtered by composing `Where`, `OrderBy(Descending)`, `ThenBy(Descending)`, `Skip` or `Take` operations.
>
> For more information on including related data, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=746393.

#### Content

I have a relationship as depicted below:

[image: Entity setup]

```cs
    public class Account
    {
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        [Key]
        public Guid Id { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();

        [ForeignKey("Customer")]
        public Guid CustomerId { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        public Customer Customer { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;

        [Required]
        public string Password { get; set; } = string.Empty;

        [Required]
        public Boolean Active { get; set; } = true;
    }
```

And when retrieving the entities from the database i'd like it to include the customer:

```cs
        public async Task<List<Account>> GetAll()
        {
            List<Account> result = await db.Account.Include(t => t.Customer).AsNoTracking().ToListAsync();
            return result;
        }
```

Then i get the *error*:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The expression 't.Customer' is invalid inside an 'Include' operation, since it does not represent a property access: 't => t.MyProperty'. To target navigations declared on derived types, use casting ('t => ((Derived)t).MyProperty') or the 'as' operator ('t => (t as Derived).MyProperty'). Collection navigation access can be filtered by composing Where, OrderBy(Descending), ThenBy(Descending), Skip or Take operations. For more information on including related data, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=746393.
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.NavigationExpandingExpressionVisitor.PopulateIncludeTree(IncludeTreeNode includeTreeNode, Expression expression, Boolean setLoaded)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.NavigationExpandingExpressionVisitor.<PopulateIncludeTree>g__TryExtractIncludeTreeNode|65_0(Expression innerExpression, String propertyName, IncludeTreeNode& addedNode, <>c__DisplayClass65_0&)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.NavigationExpandingExpressionVisitor.PopulateIncludeTree(IncludeTreeNode includeTreeNode, Expression expression, Boolean setLoaded)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.NavigationExpandingExpressionVisitor.ProcessInclude(NavigationExpansionExpression source, Expression expression, Boolean thenInclude, Boolean setLoaded)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.NavigationExpandingExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.NavigationExpandingExpressionVisitor.Expand(Expression query)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryTranslationPreprocessor.Process(Expression query)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryCompilationContext.CreateQueryExecutor[TResult](Expression query)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Database.CompileQuery[TResult](Expression query, Boolean async)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.CompileQueryCore[TResult](IDatabase database, Expression query, IModel model, Boolean async)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.<>c__DisplayClass12_0`1.<ExecuteAsync>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.CompiledQueryCache.GetOrAddQuery[TResult](Object cacheKey, Func`1 compiler)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.ExecuteAsync[TResult](Expression query, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryProvider.ExecuteAsync[TResult](Expression expression, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable`1.GetAsyncEnumerator(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredCancelableAsyncEnumerable`1.GetAsyncEnumerator()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ToListAsync[TSource]
```

Versions:

```xml
<TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
```

```xml
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="7.0.2" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="7.0.2">
```

Comment: `[NotMapped] public Customer Customer { get; set; }` <-- HINT: the `[NotMapped]` attribute, which excludes a property from EF. Why did you add this attribute in the first place?

Comment: ...and don't use `.AsNoTracking()` either, unless you **absolutely** have a good reason. Using `AsNoTracking` basically _breaks_ all of the neat functionality in `DbContext`, such as how it automagically knows what entities are loaded when they're loaded in non-`DbSet` queries.

Comment: @Dai I've always seen the `[NotMapped]` attribute as a way to tell EF: "ignore when creating table". I was not aware that it would exclude the property's entire existence from ef.

Comment: @Dai From my understanding the `AsNoTracking` method allows for faster querying, no? And whenever I use the "neat" functionality such as tracking I usually specify it. Regardless, I really appreciate all your input on code improvement. thank you!

Comment: Using `[NotMapped]` to omit columns is only applicable when used with scalar properties (`int`, `string`, etc), not FK navigation properties.

Comment: `AsNoTracking` does not make queries faster at all (the generated SQL will be the same, with or without it) - though it does _insignificantly_ speed-up the part where the `DbContext` matches query results with already-loaded entities (and related operations), but in-practice you'll find this doesn't have any significant or noticable impact on performance, and the _degredation_ it imposes on the DbContext makes for a significant developer-productivity _decrease_.

Comment: @Dai I see, noted. Great point about the scalar properties and `AsNoTracking`! If you'd like you could post it as an answer and I'll approve i. Again, thank you for resolving the question and providing additional information about code improvements, I really appreciate it!

Comment: @Dai your website link on you SO profile is broken btw

Comment: I don't have a website, I use that domain-name only for email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `class Account` accordingly:

- Remove those `[NotMapped]` attributes *except* for C# computed properties.
- Use `nameof()` instead of literal strings.
- Remove `[Required]` where applicable:

  - It's entirely redundant on non-nullable value-type properties, like `Boolean Active`.

    - (I'm unsure to what extent EF Core 7+ recognizes C# 8's `#nullable` annotations with reference-type *scalar* properties, such as `String Name` or `Byte[] SomeVarBinaryColumn` - so I'll assume you should still use them in that case)
- With reference-navigation-properties, it is this author's opinion that EF entity types should always use explicit foreign-key properties+columns with appropriate property types and attributes/annotations, *in addition* to the entity-object-returning navigation properties - and regardless of the SQL `NULL/NOT NULL` constraints on those FK columns, the entity-object-returning navigation properties should always be annotated with `?` (for nullable-reference-types): the reasoning being that reference-navigation-properties, even for a `NOT NULL`/"required" relationship *will* still return `null` unless the related entity is also loaded into the same parent `DbContext` when the FK value is not set or is otherwise invalid.

  - Fortunately your code already uses explicit FK column properties, so the only change I advocate here is to use `public Customer? Customer { get; set; }` instead of `public Customer Customer { get; set; }`.
- Also, in this author's opinion, the `= String.Empty` initializer is kinda useless, IMO.

  - Don't use property initializers to suppress the C# nullable warnings - instead use explicit directives `#pragma warning disable XXXX` and `#pragma warning restore` as this communicates developer-intent more clearly, imo.
- and lastly: **DO NOT STORE PASSWORDS AS PLAINTEXT**:

  - Remove your `String Password` column and *at the very least* use [ASP.NET Core's own `PasswordHasher`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/consumer-apis/password-hashing?view=aspnetcore-7.0).

So you should have something like this:

```
public class Account
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();

    [ForeignKey( nameof(Account.Customer) )]
    public Guid CustomerId { get; set; }

    public Customer? Customer { get; set; } // <-- Reference-Navigation-Properties are always nullable.

    [Required]
    public String Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public Byte[] SaltedPasswordHash { get; set; }; // <-- *DO NOT* store passwords as plaintext in strings. Ever.

    public Boolean Active { get; set; }; // <-- [Required] is redundant on non-Nullable<T> scalar properties.
}
```

and your query should be modified like so...

- Most async methods should have a `CancellationToken` parameter.

  - And pass that `CancellationToken` along to any async methods called.
- Add `.ConfigureAwait(false)` [inside those methods](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/configureawait-faq/), which makes your code more portable (and when run in a process with a synchronization-context it also makes your code faster as (for example) it won't need to wait to resume in the UI thread.
- Consider exposing [only covariant collection interfaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/covariance-contravariance/using-variance-in-interfaces-for-generic-collections) (e.g. `IReadOnlyList<out T>`) instead of the concrete `List<T>` type, as it allows you to avoid allocations of empty lists (as you can use `Array.Empty<T>()` instead) and other advantages.

```cs
public async Task< IReadOnlyList<Account> > GetAll( CancellationToken cancellationToken = default )
{
    List<Account> result = await this.db.Account
        .Include( t => t.Customer )
        .ToListAsync( cancellationToken ) // <-- Pass along `cancellationToken`
        .ConfigureAwait(false);

    return result;
}
```

Comment: (1) Adding `?` to reference navigation properties is absolutely wrong, as it makes them optional (as well as the associated FKs) rather than required, which might be the intended behavior (in combination with the `[Required]` attribute). The loading behaviors have nothing to do with the nullability of the data. (2) How they store passwords is off topic here, and just adds unnecessary noise

Comment: @IvanStoev I'm going to disagree with you on that: the last time I checked (EF Core 6), EF completely ignored `#nullable` annotations - and the FK column's `NULL/NOT NULL` modifiers were controlled by the FK property's `[Required]` or `Nullable<T>` (`struct`) type and the type of the Navigation Property didn't come into play.

Comment: @IvanStoev _"The loading behaviors have nothing to do with the nullability of the data"_ - Yes, **that's my point**. A simple example: _without_ the `?` modifier (for reference-types) then `new Account().Customer == null` is true, isn't it? _Therefore_ the property _can_ return `null`, therefore the property's return-type should have `?`. EF entity types have very weak class-invariants and it's wrong to assert that a property will never return `null` (by omitting the `?`) when it plainly _can_ return `null`.

Comment: But EF Core 7.0 totally changes that, so if you follow such rules, you'll be very unpleasantly surprised when you upgrade.

Comment: @IvanStoev There's no mention of EFCore 7 using `#nullable` annotations the way you're describing: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-7.0/breaking-changes

Comment: So it might be even EF Core 6 then. For sure I've seen this breaking change in NRT enabled projects, even there must be some SO posts regrading that. Anyway, all regarding NRT is here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/nullable-reference-types, and 100% NRT annotations on both primitive (string for instance) and reference navigation properties affect the database model.

Comment: I think you're thinking of the change made in ASP.NET Core 3.x's model-binding and validation. I can't repro what you're describing in EFCore7 in Linqpad in C#11.

Comment: Dai, if you look at my profile, I'm *not* answering ASP.NET Core questions, EF Core is my only area, from the very beginning, so I'm absolutely sure what I'm talking about. Also third-party tools like Linqpad are outside my interest, the only relevant tests are with C# console projects with VS.

Comment: I'll be happy to correct my answer if you can demonstrate what-you're-describing in a DotNetFiddle link or anything similar.

Comment: Everything is here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/entity-properties?tabs=data-annotations%2Cwithout-nrt#required-and-optional-properties. You can easily reproduce yourself. For instance, the simple model `public class A { public int Id { get; set; } public ICollection<B> Bs { get; set; } = new HashSet<B>(); }` and `public class B { public int Id { get; set; } public A? A { get; set; } }` and look the generated migration for the FK column/constraint. You probably are testing only with *explicit* FK property, in which case the nullability is a combination of the two.

Comment: @IvanStoev I'll concede that point - but using implicit FK columns is a bad/horrible practice. I'll update my answer.